# Access element of inner array

Tags: arrays, delphi

Given a class like this:

```
TIntClass = class
private
    myInts : TList<Integer>;
...
end;
```

how can I access an element of the inner list using the [] operator, e.g.

```
myIntList = TIntClass.Create();
myIntList[5];
```

?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to define a private function which will act as a "getter" for a default property:

**NOTE: code untested**

```
type
  TIntClass = class
  private
      // returns a value from myInts based on Index parameter
      function getItem(Index: Integer): Integer;
  private
      myInts : TList<Integer>;
  ...
  public
      property Items[Index: Integer]: Integer read getItem; default;
  end;

...
implementation

function TIntClass.getItem(Index: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := myInts[Index];
end;
```

so now you can do:

```
procedure test;
var
  LMyIntClass: TIntClass;
  L5thElemValue: Integer;
begin
  L5thElemValue := LMyIntClass[4]; // first element is accessed using LMyIntClass[0]
end;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks you very much. One question though, does this work because of 'default', 'Items' or a combination of both?

Comment: The key is the default keyword. The property can have any name.

Comment: @DaClown I forgot to mention, default tells the compiler that you can access a class variable by using the square brackets and the Items[Index: Integer] tells what type of value you can pass between the square brackets

Answer (score 0):

It should be myIntList.myInts[5], assuming that you're within the same unit so that you have access to TIntClass's private members.

Comment: That would be a way to do it, but I was looking for the way some Delphi units are doing it. For example TObjectlist allows access to the stores item via List.Items[i] and List[i]. I would like to do the same in my class.

Comment: Overload the Implicit operator as seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419266/overloading-operator-with-array